# Can't send form data with a bearer token in angular

Tags: angular, form-data, bearer-token

I'm sending form data to my backend and it's working normally, when i include a bearer token though, it doesn't work and the backend doesn't read the data.

Here's what i'm doing :

Component.ts

```js
send() {
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('title', this.form.value.title);
    formData.append('description', this.form.value.description);

    this.service.add(formData).subscribe(data => {
      console.log(data);
    });
}
```

Service. In this code back read the data.

```js
add(data) {
    return this.http.post(url, data);
}
```

But it does not work in this code :

```js
add(data) {
    const headers = new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        Authorization: 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem('token')
    });
    return this.http.post(url, data, {headers});
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try like this:

```
var header = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders()
    .set('Authorization',  'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem('token'))
}

 return this.http.post(url, data, header);
```

Comment: I want to upvote, but stackoverflow sais:
- Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.